# Dealing with quotes in Windows batch scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file, quotes, scripting

In a Windows batch file, when you do the following:

> `set myvar="c:\my music & videos"`

the variable `myvar` is stored with the quotes included. Honestly I find that very stupid. The quotes are just to tell where the string begins and ends, not to be stored as part of the value itself.
How can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh my - you're taking the first steps into the truly maddening areas of cmd scripting.  Good luck - you're going to need it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180754/best-free-resource-for-learning-advanced-batch-file-usage/180767#180767 for a pointer to a good book and some advice.

Comment: Very stupid is a mild way to put it. I hope the real reason is some weird legacy compatibility stuff.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
set "myvar=c:\my music & videos"
```

Notice the quotes start before myvar.  It's actually that simple.
Side note: myvar can't be echoed afterwards unless it's wrapped in quotes because & will be read as a command separator, but it'll still work as a path.

http://ss64.com/nt/set.html under "Variable names can include Spaces"

Comment: it can actually be echoed, you just have to wrap it in quotes ;) `echo "%myvar%"`

Comment: @Fowl but then the doublequotes get echoed too.

Comment: if you wrap the path to an executable like this, you will need to quote it on invocation "%msbuild%"

Answer (score 67):

This is the correct way to do it:

```
set "myvar=c:\my music & videos"
```

The quotes will not be included in the variable value.

Comment: Very useful, though this answer deserves the credit http://stackoverflow.com/a/8582277/781695

Comment: How is your answer any different than [@RuskoGuyachev's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8582277/1098603) that was written one year earlier?

Comment: Much clearer "The quotes will not be included in the variable value."

Answer (score 36):

It depends on how you want to use the variable. If you just want to use the value of the variable without the quotes you can use either delayed expansion and string substitution, or the `for` command:

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

set myvar="C:\my music & videos"
```

As andynormancx states, the quotes are needed since the string contains the `&`. Or you can escape it with the `^`, but I think the quotes are a little cleaner.

If you use delayed expansion with string substitution, you get the value of the variable without the quotes:

```
@echo !myvar:"=!
>>> C:\my music & videos
```

You can also use the `for` command:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%P in (%myvar%) do (
    @echo %%P
)
>>> C:\my music & videos
```

However, if you want to use the variable in a command, you must use the quoted value or enclose the value of the variable in quotes:

1. Using string substitution and delayed expansion to use value of the variable without quotes, but use the variable in a command:

   ```
   @echo OFF
   SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

   set myvar="C:\my music & videos"
   md %myvar%
   @echo !myvar:"=! created.
   ```
2. Using the `for` command to use the value of the variable without quotes, but you'll have to surround the variable with quotes when using it in commands:

   ```
   @echo OFF
   set myvar="C:\my music & videos"

   for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%P in (%myvar%) do (
       md "%%P"
       @echo %%P created.
   )
   ```

Long story short, there's really no clean way to use a path or filename that contains embedded spaces and/or `&`s in a batch file.

Comment: Excellent answer . . . but it made my head hurt . . .

Comment: @Binary Worrier; yeah, batch files tend to do that ;)

Comment: You must be some sort of batch file God. Such glorious clever idiocy ;)

Answer (score 8):

The Windows command interpreter allows you to use the quotes around the entire set command (valid in every version of windows NT from NT 4.0 to Windows 2012 R2)

Your script should just be written as follows:

```cmd
@echo OFF

set "myvar=C:\my music & videos"
```

Then you may put quotes around the variables as needed.

Working with the CMD prompt can seem esoteric at times, but the command interpreter actually behaves pretty solidly in obeying it's internal logic, you just need to re-think things.

In fact, the set command does not require you to use quotes at all, but both the way you are doing your variable assignment and the way the ,method of using no quotes can cause you to have extra spaces around your variable which are hard to notice when debugging your script.

e.g. Both of the below are technically Valid, but you can have trailing spaces, so it's not a good practice:

```cmd
set myvar=some text   
set myvar="some text"
```

e.g. Both of the below are good methods for setting variables in Windows Command interpreter, however the double quote method is superior:

```cmd
set "myvar=Some text"
(set myvar=Some value)
```

Both of these leave nothing to interpretation the variable will have exactly the data you are looking for.

**strong text**  However, for your purposes, only the quoted method will work validly because you are using a reserved character

Thus, you would use:

```cmd
set "myvar=c:\my music & videos"
```

However, even though the variable IS correctly set to this string, when you ECHO the sting the command interpreter will interpret the ampersand as the keyword to indicate another statement follows.

SO if you want to echo the string from the variable the CMD interpreter still needs to be told it's a text string, or if you do not want the quotes to show you have to do one of the following:

echo the variable WITH Quotes:

```cmd
Echo."%myvar%"
```

echo the variable WITHOUT Quotes:

```cmd
Echo.%myvar:&=^&%
<nul SET /P="%myvar%"
```

In the above two scenarios you can echo the string with no quotes just fine.  Example output below:

```cmd
C:\Admin>    Echo.%myvar:&=^&%
C:\my music & videos

C:\Admin>    <nul SET /P="%myvar%"
C:\my music & videos
C:\Admin>
```

Comment: You can always use a variable in a safe way with delayed expansion. `echo(!myvar!` This doesn't needs quotes for the output

Answer (score 7):

Use jscript.

Many moons ago (i.e. about 8 years give or take) I was working on a large C++/VB6 project, and I had various bits of Batch Script to do parts of the build.

Then someone pointed me at the [Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html), I was particularly enamoured of point 2, and set about bringing all my little build scripts into one single build script . . .

and it nearly broke my heart, getting all those little scripts working together, on different machines, with slightly different setups, ye Gods it was dreadful - particularly setting variables and parameter passing. It was really brittle, the slightest thing would break it and require 30 minutes of tweaking to get going again.

Eventually - I can be stubborn me - **I chucked the whole lot in and** in about a day **re-wrote it all in JavaScript**, running it from the command prompt with CScript.

I haven't looked back. Although these days it's MSBuild and Cruise Control, if I need to do something even slightly involved with a batch script, I use jscript.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, but since I already have been to the la-la-land of cmd.exe string escaping inside and outside of batch files, I totally agree with you. +1

Comment: Goes without saying that these days it's all Powershell.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Mental, surely you'd get with the times and use FAKE ? (Not actually joking BTW, it's great) (Disclaimer: have not 100% ascertained that you and/or OP are talking about build scripts - just here on a stalker basis!)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the escape character '^', e.g.

```
set myvar=c:\my music ^& videos
```

You'll have you be careful when you expand myvar because the shell might not treat the & as a literal.  If the above doesn't work, try inserting a caret into the string too:

```
set myvar=c:\my music ^^^& videos
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. Don't use spaces or other characters that are special to the command interpreter in path names (directory or file names).  If you use only letters, numbers, underscores, and hyphens (and a period before the extension to identify the file type), your scripting life will become immeasurably simpler.

   I have written and otherwise collected a plethora of tools over the years, including a DOS utility that will rename files.  (It began as something that just removed spaces from filenames, but morphed into something that will replace characters or strings within the filenames, even recursively.)  If anyone's interested, I will get my long-neglected web site up and running and post this and others.

   That said, variables aren't just for holding pathnames, so...
2. As others have already pointed out, **SET "myvar=c:\my music & videos"** is the correct workaround for such a variable value.  (Yes, I said workaround.  I agree that your initial inclination to just quote the value ("my music & videos") is far more intuitive, but it is what it is, as they say.