# How to change the path to php.ini in PHP CLI version

Tags: command-line-interface, php

The php that run on the webserver and the CLI version is not using the same php.ini file. If I do a command `php --ini`, it show this

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

while my web version uses the php.ini in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini`. This is probably very common for people using wamp.

How do I change the Loaded Configuration File to read from `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini` so I don't have to maintain 2 different php.ini versions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Per http://php.net/configuration.file:

> php.ini is searched for in these locations (in order):
>
> - SAPI module specific location (PHPIniDir directive in Apache 2, -c command line option in CGI and CLI, php_ini parameter in NSAPI, PHP_INI_PATH environment variable in THTTPD)
> - The PHPRC environment variable. Before PHP 5.2.0, this was checked after the registry key mentioned below.
> - As of PHP 5.2.0, the location of the php.ini file can be set for different versions of PHP. The following registry keys are examined in order:
>
>   - [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y.z], [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y] and [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x], where x, y and z mean the PHP major, minor and release versions. If there is a value for IniFilePath in any of these keys, the first one found will be used as the location of the php.ini (Windows only).
>   - [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP], value of IniFilePath (Windows only).
> - Current working directory (except CLI).
> - The web server's directory (for SAPI modules), or directory of PHP (otherwise in Windows).
> - Windows directory (C:\windows or C:\winnt) (for Windows), or --with-config-file-path compile time option.

For CLI, your best bet is probably either to set the `$PHPRC` environment variable for the account that will be executing scripts, or recompile PHP with a different `--with-config-file-path` configuration setting.

You can also override the php.ini search dir on a per-execution basis by specifying the `-c` option when invoking PHP:

```
> php --help
Usage: php [options] [-f]  [--] [args...]
...
  -c | Look for php.ini file in this directory
```

Comment: so, it's a windows machine running wamp. How do I set the $PHPRC?

Comment: it's just an environment variable, google for 'set environment variable windows' should give tutorials.

Answer (score 16):

By specifying environment variable PHPRC to point to the same php.ini as the one Apache uses worked for me on Ubuntu

```
export PHPRC=/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Or put it in the $HOME/.bashrc to import every time cli is started

Comment: When I did this, it worked the first time but when I needed to change it again I had to remove the `/php.ini` part and just use the path to get it to work.

Comment: If I set the same php.ini for both CLI and normal PHP, then I get alot of "dynamic file could not get loaded" errors when I execute `php -i`

Answer (score 7):

I tried and failed with using C:\YourPathto\PHP7\ as my PHPRC Environmental Variable.
But it must be set to the full path with filename. I also found that I had to do a full restart for php to pick up the new variable.

1. On Windows, find the path to your php.ini file and modify and run the following command in a command window:

   `setx PHPRC "C:\YourPathto\PHP7\php.ini"`

   You should see `SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.`
2. Then restart your computer (really).

Or edit environmental variables through the regular way, then restart:

[image: PHPRC Environmental Variable Set to C:\YourPathto\PHP7\php.ini]

Comment: Perfect I use mamp, it used some weird path for the php.ini and aliased it to use the config but it didn't work in composer scripts now it does thanks to that environment variable!

Answer (score 2):

I have spent about 3 hours trying to do exactly what your question asks. Couldn't do it. I gave up and copied that php.ini to C:\Windows and changed my ENV variable "PHPRC" to C:\Windows (and in httpd.conf). That way both my CLI php and Apach php e are using the same file. I could not get "php -m" to display the modules I had loaded in my php.ini for the life of me until I made this change...

Comment: This was the key for me. I actually removed the PHPRC environment variable and rebooted and php defaulted to looking in the same path as the current working directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
set "PHPRC=C:\YourPathto\PHP7\php.ini"
```

Important the quotes start **before** PHPRC. See [Dealing with quotes in Windows batch scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535975/dealing-with-quotes-in-windows-batch-scripts)

Comment: Please add code block like it's explain here : https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/1213575

Comment: You're the hero we need but don't deserve. On windows, this is what gets it to finally work.

Answer (score 0):

try running the `phpinfo()` function on both side

Webserver and CLI and find out the exact location of your `php.ini` file for both side

and maintain those files only

Comment: I already know the both files locations. The question is how to unify them.