# cakePHP and EasyPHP cannot bake

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to use the "cake bake" command with cakephp, 
but whenever i try to call that command i get:

```
What would you like to Bake? (D/M/V/C/P/F/T/Q)
> m
---------------------------------------------------------------
Bake Model
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\test\app\Model\
---------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
#0 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\test\lib\Cake\Model\ConnectionManager.php(105): DboSource->__construct(Array)
#1 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\test\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTask.php(948): ConnectionManager::getDataSource('defa
ult')
#2 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\test\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTask.php(885): ModelTask->getAllTables(NULL)
#3 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\test\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTask.php(975): ModelTask->listAll(NULL)
#4 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\test\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTask.php(203): ModelTask->getName()
#5 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\test\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTask.php(91): ModelTask->_interactive()
#6 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\test\lib\Cake\Console\Command\BakeShell.php(109): ModelTask->execute()
#7 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\test\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php(440): BakeShell->main()
#8 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\test\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(209): Shell->runCommand(NULL, Array)
#9 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\test\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(66): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#10 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\test\app\Console\cake.php(47): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#11 {main}
```

i have read and tried all the solutions i found on google and stackoverflow but none of them worked, 
and the connection is fine when i just implement my own model, controller and view.

Comment: Well, what exactly is it that you have already tried? I wouldn't want to shoot in the dark just to hear that you've already tried that.

Comment: i followed this video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olXzCpVbIF8

Comment: and i tried to change "localhost" to 127.0.0.1, tried running cmd as an admin, i double and triple checked the username and password and database name

Comment: Do you maybe have a separate php.ini for the CLI (`php -i | find /i "Configuration File"`)? If so, make sure that it has PDO enabled (`extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`).

Comment: i cant find the "Loaded Configuration File" but i can see "PDO support => enabled"

Comment: ah omg ... i see it now (after running : php -i | find /i "Configuration File")

Comment: it turned out that the CLI is not set to the easyphp ini file, how can i change it?

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844641/how-to-change-the-path-to-php-ini-in-php-cli-version**

Comment: yes, i checked that, but i didnt find the "Software/PHP" directory in registry, and i i didnt find the "PHPRC" variable in the "System variables"

Comment: anyways, just post ur solution, i changed that ini files, and it worked like a charm :D thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It says there connection to Mysql is missing.

Make sure you have MySQL installed in your server first.

Then,have you changed your database configuration in /app/Config/database.php? You need to setup your database first.

If you already did that, have you test the connection? running localhost/yourwebfolder will display if you already set up CakePHP correctly before you can proceed with "baking"

Comment: @ndm already found the solution, its in the comments, waiting for him to post it as an answer to accept it, thank you though..