# Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() [Cron job only]

Tags: php, cron, lamp

When running a php script by navigating to the file directly on the server (via the web), everything runs fine.

However, when setting up the same file to run via a cron job, I get the error message:

```
Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()
```

The cron job is set up to run this file, with permission 744:

```
php -q /home/username/public_html/seafood/php/lobsteremail.php
```

Any idea why a file might run fine manually but not as part of a cron job?

Comment: you should enable the mysqli extension in your cli php.ini

Comment: Checking my phpInfo page, mysqli is already active (it works fine when running the file manually.) Additionally, inside my php.ini file, I have the following line extension=pdo_mysql.so, which should enable mysqli by default for php 5.4?

Comment: it's not necessarely the same php.ini for web and cli... check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844641/how-to-change-the-path-to-php-ini-in-php-cli-version

Comment: @JustinMathieu If you solved the issue please let me know. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is your cron job set to run on boot?
If so, it cant find mysqli_connect() because mysql is not running yet.
Before calling the php script, you need to wait.

```
Sleep 10 # wait for mysql
php -q /home/username/public_html/seafood/php/lobsteremail.php
```