# How to set custom php.ini location in lighttpd?

Tags: php, lighttpd

By default my `php.ini` is located at `/etc/php.ini` and I want to move it to `/tmp/ab/etc/php.ini`. In `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` I've tried to set the following configuration:

```
#### CGI module
cgi.assign = ( ".pl"  => "/usr/bin/perl", ".cgi" => "/usr/bin/perl", ".py"  => "/usr/bin/python", "cgi-bin/luci" => "", ".php"  => "/usr/bin/php-cgi -c /tmp/ab/etc/php.ini", "sms_gateway" => "/bin/bash", "cgi-bin/check" => "/bin/sh", "cgi-bin/remove" => "/bin/sh", "cgi-bin/date" => "/bin/sh" )
```

Please take a look at this part: `".php"  => "/usr/bin/php-cgi -c /tmp/ab/etc/php.ini"`

But after I do that and restart lighttpd and I try to check the location of `php.ini` with:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

I get `500 - Internal Server Error` on my browser. How can I do this ?

Comment: I am not sure it's good way, but you can move `php.ini` to `/tmp/ab/etc` and in `/etc/` create symlink called `php.ini` to `/tmp/ab/etc`

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to create a wrapper script /tmp/ab/bin/my-php-cgi and put that in lighttpd.conf `cgi.assign = ( ".php"  => "/tmp/ab/bin/my-php-cgi" )`

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi -c /tmp/ab/etc/php.ini
```

Depending on the PHP version you are using you might also look into having lighttpd.conf `setenv.add-environment = ( "PHPRC" => "/tmp/ab/etc/php.ini" )`  See also [How to change the path to php.ini in PHP CLI version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844641/how-to-change-the-path-to-php-ini-in-php-cli-version)