# cURL installed, undefined function curl_init()

Tags: php, curl, wamp

PHP is throwing the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

- The `php.ini` cURL line: `extension=php_curl.dll`.
- The `php.ini` extensions line: `extension_dir = "C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAMP\PHP\ext"`.
- Shows up in `phpinfo()` as expected.
- `libeay32.dll`, `ssleay32.dll`, `libcrypto-*.dll`, `libssl-*.dll` and `libssh2.dll` are in the PHP directory.
- Windows 7 x64 / PHP 7.3.12.
- Restarted Apache, three times like you always told me.
- Original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844641/how-to-change-the-path-to-php-ini-in-php-cli-version) and related posts do not contain applicable answers/suggestions.

**PHP**

```
$curl_handle = curl_init($url);
```

Apache error log:

> [Tue Nov 26 00:15:39.193774 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 5312:tid 1108] [client ::1:58444]
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in D:\functions.php:149
>
> Stack trace:
>
> 0 D:\functions.php(57): **function_name_here**(Object(a), Array, '17.96')
>
> 1 D:\functions.php(27): **function_name_here**(Object(a), Array, '17.96')
>
> 2 D:\post.php(6): **function_name_here**(Object(a), Array)
>
> 3 D:\index.php(7): include('D:\\My Documents...')
>
> 4 {main}
>
> thrown in D:\functions.php on line 149, referer: https://localhost/

## Update, Command Line:

`C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAMP\PHP>php -r "curl_init();"`

> PHP Deprecated:  Directive 'track_errors' is deprecated in Unknown on line 0
>
> Deprecated: Directive 'track_errors' is deprecated in Unknown on line 0

What am I missing?

Comment: did you check for active curl with `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: @AnatoliyR Yeah, I can add an explicit item for it though you can see above the `;` isn't present / it's "installed".

Comment: Well, something happens here so need to count all possibilities. Therefore, another question: is it possible that you run curl under different PHP instance? For example you run it form command line while you report apache based instance for curl settings and phpinfo()?

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: @Hamid As denoted by the `wamp` tag, Windows; 7 x64 specifically.

Comment: @AnatoliyR I need to run multiple instances of PHP and I'd rather reinstall if it sadly comes to a choice like that.

Comment: OK, check the Apache error log in and paste here. some old files or incorrect PATH make it.

Comment: @Hamid Updated question with details.

Comment: at first make sure that you are using wamp PHP not windows IIS php. (Your extension path is in `c:` but your php file is in your document folder! it's not correct unless you had a specific VirtualHost)

Comment: @Hamid I don't use IIS (played with it once over a decade ago and not on this install of Windows). My software runs in the My Documents folder (which in *this* version of Windows is called "User Files"). One has to registry hack to force it to be a different drive (because you *will, not if* need to format C:\). I'm not using any virtual hosts.