# How to change the path for additional php.ini files

Tags: php, command-line-interface

If I run `php --ini`,then I get the following warnings.

```
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
PHP Warning:  Module 'memcached' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
....
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/Qapache/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/Qapache/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /opt/Qapache/etc
Additional .ini files parsed:      /opt/Qapache/etc/php.ini
```

Yeah, i run a Qnap NAS.
If I comment out the modules in the php.ini like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764981/php-warning-module-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0), they will not be loaded anymore.

So my thought is that the php.ini file is loaded twice by the path for "Scan for additional .ini files in:".

I know that I can override the php execution with the following command
`php -c /PATH/TO/php.ini -n` so it looks like this.

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/Qapache/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /PATH/TO/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

And that works, none module was already loaded.

But this is not persistent and I don't want to use the options for it every time.
So, how do I change the path for `Scan for additional .ini files in:` in general?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844641/how-to-change-the-path-to-php-ini-in-php-cli-version

Comment: @Dilek If I understand this correctly, the question refers to the main php.ini. Also the variable $PHPRC. Accordingly, it does not refer to the additional paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That directory is defined when PHP is compiled from source code using the custom flag `--with-config-file-scan-dir`:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php#configure.options.php

You can change it at run time by setting an ENV var called `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` as defined in the documentation:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php#configuration.file.scan

Comment: Setting the ENV works. Thank. But shouldn't the flag be `--with-config-file-scan-dir`, according to your second link?
`--with-config-file-path` should be for the main `php.ini`.

Comment: @itchybellybutton You are indeed right, I have modified my answer.