# Command line: Create folders in subfolders with spaces

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd

For a project I received 700 folders with names of institutions (containing spaces).
The purpose is now to create subfolders in each of these folders.

[institution folder]\Documents\
[institution folder]\Images\
[institution folder]\Videos\

According some posts here the below script should work to create the Documents folder

```
FOR /d %A IN (C:\Users\myname\project\institutions\*) DO mkdir %A\Documents
```

However, I notice in the feedback that I get from the command line that this instruction fails at the spaces in the foldername. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FOR /d %A IN (C:\Users\myname\project\institutions\*) DO mkdir "%A"\Documents
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you wrap expressions containing spaces with `"` to make sure the shell sees them as a single entity.

Comment: Yes I know, but the problem is, how do I handle that with my %A variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535975/dealing-with-quotes-in-windows-batch-scripts

Comment: CLI feedback: "%A" is not expected at this moment.

Comment: have you looked at that link i posted last? sounds like it has your solution in there

Comment: You place the quotes around the `%A` in the `MKDIR`, but not in the `FOR` thus: `FOR /d %A IN (C:\Users\myname\project\institutions\*) DO mkdir "%A"\Documents`

Comment: Thx @PeterWright, that worked for me. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.