# Batch file to create subfolder in other subfolders, but only at top level

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, directory

I have a similar problem to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634351/command-line-create-folders-in-subfolders-with-spaces), but I couldn't get the solution to work (I'm a total novice).

I have a set of folders on a network drive, each folder named after a manager (e.g. `\sfnetfile\DEPT\HR_Manager\Manager, Test` and `\sfnetfile\DEPT\HR_Manager\Manager, Test 2`). I am trying to get a folder/subfolder combo created in each manager folder of `2013\Variable`. In some cases managers already have a `2013` subfolder, but not the `Variable` sub-subfolder (excuse the silly terminology).

I also want to prevent the batch file from creating the `2013\Variable` folder in existing other subfolders within each manager folders (so I don't want it, for example, creating another level down: `\sfnetfile\DEPT\HR_Manager\Manager, Test 2\2012\2013\Variable`.

Here is my code:

```
FOR /d %A IN (\sfnetfile\DEPT\HR_Manager*) DO mkdir "%A"\2013\Variable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
@echo off

for /d %%d in (\\sfnetfile\DEPT\HR_Manager\*) do md "%%~d\2013\Variable" 2>nul
```

assuming that `sfnetfile` is the name of a remote server and `DEPT` is a shared folder on that server. If `sfnetfile` is a top level folder on a mapped network drive, change that to:

```
@echo off

for /d %%d in (X:\sfnetfile\DEPT\HR_Manager\*) do md "%%~d\2013\Variable" 2>nul
```

where `X:` is the drive letter of the network drive.

**Edit:** As @dbenham correctly mentions, redirecting error output (to suppress error messages for existing leaf folders) will also suppress any other error message. A more sophisticated approach would check if the folder doesn't already exist and only then create it:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /d %%d in (\\sfnetfile\DEPT\HR_Manager\*) do (
  set "folder=%%~d\2013\Variable"
  if exist "!folder!" (
    if not exist "!folder!\" echo "!folder!" exists as a file! 1>&2
  ) else (
    mkdir "!folder!"
  )
)
```

Comment: +1, An alternative to redirecting stderr to nul is to prefix the MD with `if not exist "%%d\2013\Variable\"`. The one advantage of this is you will see an error message if a file named Variable exists that is preventing the creation of the folder.