# How to replace single quote to double quote by awk when under Windows?

Tags: windows, awk, file-processing

I tried gsub() but it didn't work. Here is the command:

```
awk -v a="'"  b=" \" "  "gsub(a,b,$0){print $0}" D:\re.json
```

or anybody could tell me what is the right escape character in Windows command line?

Comment: try `\047`. Usual advice in Windows is dont try to fight the crazy quoting - just put your awk script in a file and execute it tin `-f`.

Comment: I used \047 but it said "backslash not last character on line."  How to solve this error? Thank you very much.

Comment: @wanderlustwei put it in a file.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, put the script into a file.  Referring to Windows, we would understand the context to be Windows batch-files (rather than say, mingw which has its own problems with command-line scripting).  For Windows batch files

- double-quotes are eaten before the program sees them
- there is no well-documented way to escape double-quotes
- single-quotes are passed as-is to the program (and are not, as in Bourne shell, used for quoting).

Here are a few links where those issues are discussed:

- [Dealing with quotes in Windows batch scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535975/dealing-with-quotes-in-windows-batch-scripts)
- [What does single quote do in windows batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173825/what-does-single-quote-do-in-windows-batch-files)
- [Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)

So the rules are entirely different from what awk needs for this construction.  The last link by the way gives some clues that you might use to devise a workaround (at the expense of readability).  It is also discussed in [Escaping Double Quotes in Batch Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562038/escaping-double-quotes-in-batch-script).

As a separate file, the script would also be more readable, e.g., call that `foo.awk`:

```
gsub("'"," \" ",$0){print $0}
```

and use it as

```
awk -f foo.awk D:\re.json
```

Comment: No need to write `{print $0}` or to provide the` $0` arg or `gsub()` - that's the default behavior. The whole script would just be `gsub(/'/," \" ")`. I also changed the delimiters for the first arg for gsub() since it is an RE, not a string - won't change the behavior in this case but will in others so a good habit to get into.

Comment: I changed the question's script minimally to show the effect of the quoting alone.  If it were something to recommend, I would show the way a `^`-escaped workaround would look as well -- but the result would be hard to read and not reusable.